# About "top" and "bottom" with relative position

Tags: html, css, css-position

so, I have a confusion about the behavior of `top` and `bottom` when we apply `position: relative;` on a div.

here is my code snippet:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.parent{
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    margin:100px;
}
.relative{
    background:#ff0;
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    right:100px;
    left:100px;
    bottom:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS position relative question</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--here, I have used div as a "parent" to apply some margin.-->
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="relative"></div>
    </div>        
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am confused why `bottom:200px;` is not applied to box? In CSS, Isn't it true that the last defined rule is applied? so, in my code, I have defined `bottom:200px;` in the last. shouldn't it overwrite `top:100px;` like `left:100px;` overwriting `right:100px;`?

I know, the question seems confusing, but I have tried hard to explain it simply.but, if it is still not understandable, I am happy to try again. :)

Comment: Where are you applying `position: static` to anything?

Comment: And WHY? There is very little reason ever to apply static position to any element. Perhaps you have misunderstood what positioning does.

Comment: Parent must be in position relative, and child absolute. So top, right, bottom, left work.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am applying "position:relative" to the "div" with class="relative". :)

Comment: @BossCOTIGA no, actually, I was trying to know about the behavior of "top" and "bottom" when "position" is set to "relative".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#relative-positioning):

> If **neither 'left' nor 'right' is 'auto'**, the position is over-constrained, and **one of them has to be ignored**. If the 'direction' property of the containing block is 'ltr', the value of 'left' wins and 'right' becomes -'left'. If 'direction' of the containing block is 'rtl', 'right' wins and 'left' is ignored.

So it's not about the order of the CSS but the direction which is in most of the case `ltr` so left will always win. Same logic for `bottom` and `top` if you continue reading the Specification.

> If neither is 'auto', **'bottom' is ignored** (i.e., the used value of 'bottom' will be minus the value of 'top').

Comment: so, here "direction" is not specified in my code, therefore it is "ltr" by default  and "left" property is applied and same goes with the "top" and "bottom",i.e. "bottom" is ignored and "top" is applied to the box.